# Math 110C, Multivariable Calculus, Second Derivatives Test

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

How can I find local maximum and minimum values and saddle points of $f(x,y)=xy+e^{-(xy)}$?

First I found the first partial derivatives:

$f_x=y-ye^{-xy}$ and $f_y=x-xe^{-xy}$

and then got $0=y-ye^{-xy}$ and $0=x-xe^{-xy}$

Next I plugged in $0=x-xe^{-xy}\implies x=xe^{-xy} \implies 1=e^{-xy}$ into $0=y-ye^{-xy}$:

$0=y-ye^{-xy} \implies y=ye^{-xy} \implies 1=e^{-xy} \implies$ (plug in) $\implies e^{-xy} = e^{-xy} \implies 0 = 0$

which i think means all points $(x,y)$ on the x- and y- axes are critical points

After that I found the second partial derivatives:

$f_{xx}=y^2e^{-xy}$ and $f_{xy}= 1-e^{-xy}+xye^{-xy}$ [i could have made a mistake here, i am not sure] and $f_{yy} = x^2e^{-xy}$

Later I plugged that into the Second Derivatives Test and got:

$D(x,y)=(y^2e^{-xy})(x^2e^{-xy})-(1-e^{-xy}+xye^{-xy})^2$

Finally I used $(0,0)$ as a test point and got:

$D(0,0) = 0 - (1-1)^2 = 0$ which fails the Second Derivatives Test

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. The answer is supposed to be Minima $f(x,y)=1$ at all points (x,y) on x- and y-axes

Answer (score 1):

All your calculations are correct and since $D(0,y)=D(x,0)=0,$ the [second derivative test](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SecondDerivativeTest.html) is nonconclusive.
What you can do instead is notice that
$$f(x,y)=g(xy)$$
and study
$$g(t):=t+e^{-t},$$
which is much easier.

Comment: If it's nonconclusive, how am I supposed to find the answer of  "Minima (,)=1
 at all points (x,y) on x- and y-axes" ?

Comment: By studying the extrema of $g.$

Comment: OH, so I need to solve it again but this time for ():=+$^(−)$?

Comment: It is much easier: it has only 1 variable

Comment: Sorry, I have bad memory, what test would I use to solve that?

Comment: The same but with 1 variable. Calculate the critical point(s) i.e. solve $g'(t)=0,$ and at that point look at the sign of $g''.$ Or simply here: study $g$ globally (sign of $g'$ and global minimum).

Comment: I did it!!! Thank you for your help!

Comment: The [global study of $g$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+x%2Be%5E%7B-x%7D) brings more information: the minimum is global.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers